# Problem with fetching mail using TMail in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tmail

While fetching email, TMail appears to parse the email body twice,when I use this code.All the other parameters are fine(from_email,email_subject).
Any ideas?

```
def get_mail
  Net::POP3.enable_ssl(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)  
  Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, "uname","pass") do |pop|  
  mail_header=[];mail_subject=[];mail_body=[];mail_from=[]
    unless pop.mails.empty?
       pop.each_mail do |mail|  
        email = TMail::Mail.parse(mail.pop)
        mail_subject =  email.subject
        mail_body =  email.body
        mail_from = email.from
        email_obj=EmailedQueries.new
        email_obj.save_email(mail_from, mail_subject, mail_body)          
        end 
    end
 end   
end
```

Comment: what does save_email do with the body? Perhaps it is going through the body once when you parse it, and once when you do something meaningful with it in save_email ?

Answer (score 0):

No idea ;-)

I've no clue what your real problem is. But have you tried the (new?) mail gem - it's used in Rails3: http://github.com/mikel/mail .